# ¿Alguien sabe si el rendimiento de Genexus es mejor en procesadores Intel o Ryzen Amd?

Tags: genexus

Estoy presupuestando una computadora de escritorio y no sé si la performance del desarrollo local de aplicaciones genexus es mejor a nivel de mononúcleo, multinucleo, etc. En el primer caso sé qué es mejor Intel, y en el segundo Ryzen. Pero soy nuevo en Gx y me gustaría saber mejor sobre sus experiencias.

Answer (score 1):

Genexus permite configurar generación en paralelo por lo cual tener múltiples núcleos es una mejor opción.

Te recomiendo que veas la documentación con las recomendaciones sobre este tema https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?25808,Multiple+Concurrent+Generator+and+Specifier+Instances